# Regarding quantum support vector machine using qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I would like to ask, how can I add my own .csv data file to run a quantum support vector machine using qiskit ? I don't want to use already existing datasets in sklearn, scikit-learn library.

Comment: What data do you have in this .csv file? Would it be possible to just use python to open and parse/read the file, and then use the data within qiskit once it has been read from the file?

Comment: Yes, only python is enough to read my .csv data file. Would you please share your email, so that I can send it

Comment: If it is the file-reading part that you need help with then I think the Python docs for their csv reader/writer library should help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I am still not getting, I want to run quantum svm code, mentioned in my question, where a python programe is mentioned, I just want to ask, how should I use or where I should put my .csv data file, if you can share your email, i can show my data file, thanks..!!

Comment: Please can you close one of your questions so that all the discussion can be kept in one place :) It may be useful to other people in future

Comment: I am using it first time, can you please tell me how to close it ?

Comment: I am not sure, because  I have to write /edit code according to my data file, I mean parameters have to update accordingly, which is not clear to me, thats what I want to show you my data file

Comment: You can use the pandas library to import custom datasets and it also has a very easy syntax.